# strange behavior of delete key in Vim on iTerm / Mac

Tags: iterm

When I press delete (Fn + Backspace) in normal mode, the cursor jumps several lines ahead. When I press it in Edit mode, nothing happens (characters are not being deleted).

I have "Natural Text Editing" preset in Profiles > Keys > Key Mappings. This behavior persist with and without "Delete Key Sends ^H".

In MacOS native Terminal app, the Delete key works as expected

I am using MacBook Pro (13-inch, M2, 2022) with russian keyboard.

Is there a way to see what sequence iTerm it actually sends?

Answer (score 1):

Removing "Send Hex Codes: 0x4" from iTerm2 -> Profiles -> Settings -> Keys -> Key Mappings solved the problem for me.